# Shutdown Windows machine remotely without telnet/ssh

Tags: windows, linux, shutdown, rpc

I have been trying to shutdown a remote XP machine but cannot get it to budge.

**I did the following on the Windows box:**

- Ensured no firewall
- Started Remote Registry Editing service
- Shared a network drive (to enable file sharing?)
- Created a user 'shutdown' specifically for shutting down
- Added 'shutdown' to Administrators group
- Added 'shutdown' to the list of allowed shutdown users in gpedit.msc

**Here's what I have tried:**

From Windows 7 box:

- `shutdown -m computer` (Access denied message)
- `psshutdown -m computer` (Access denied message)
- `runas /user:computer\shutdown "cmd /K shutdown -m computer` (access denied)
- `runas /user:shutdown "cmd /K shutdown -m computer` (access denied)

From Linux box:

- `net rpc shutdown -I computer -U user%password` (says shutdown succeeded)
- `rpcclient -I x.x.x.x -c shutdown -U user` (gives usage message)

Is there anyway to shut it down without resorting to telnet / ssh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to these links ([1](http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-access-is-denied_topic547.html), [2](http://forum.sysinternals.com/access-denied-windows-xp-pro-sp2_topic1411.html), [3](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/21113-remote-shutdownpsshutdown-problems/)) you are most likely sending the `psshutdown` command as a guest user.

First, [turn off simple file and printer sharing](http://compnetworking.about.com/cs/winxpnetworking/ht/winxpsfs.htm). Next, [enable normal file and printer sharing](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/windowsfilesharing/ht/enable_disable.htm).

Then instead of `psshutdown`, try:

```
psexec -u <xp_home_user> -p <password> \\xpMachine notepad
```

If Notepad opens, then that means `psshutdown` should work! Try:

```
psshutdown.exe \\xpMachine -t 10 -f -u Administrator -p password
```

I notice you said you had tried:

```
psshutdown -m computer
```

However you should note that [the `psshutdown` command requires a `\\` and a password](http://www.grape-info.com/doc/win2000srv/power/remoteshutdown.html).

Comment: Thank you very much!  All I had to do was turn off simple file and printer sharing.   Also TIL how to enable the security tab on files :)